# Cannot Connect to New Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

Disclaimer, I'm not a dba. I have been handed the job and have to do it. For day to day operations, I can handle the job, but now they want to upgrade the server and I'm stuck on this one issue.

I have 2 MS SQL servers, an older 2008 SQL server and a new 2016 SQL Server. I am replacing the old with the new. The servers are separated by network zones. The old server has been operating for a very long time. I have configured the new server with the same configurations as the old. I configured the servers using the same IP address.

I am able to connect to the new 2016 server via UDL file from another server in the same network zone. I am unable to connect from a different network zone via UDL.

I am able to connect to the old 2008 server from a server on the same network zone, AND a different network zone.

My question. Is there somewhere I should be allowing traffic from another network zone to the database server? or is there something else going on? The firewall rules are set up correctly by the network team (firewall is handled at the network level).

Comment: If "configured the servers using the same IP address." they have to be on isolated networks.  You would normally configure them with different IP addresses.

Comment: Configured with the same IP address meaning that the old server was disconnected and the new server was connected.